# Dequeuing scripts for all pages but the home page

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, conditional-tags

I'm trying to dequeue some scripts from a plugin that I only need for the home page. For the home page, I'm using a file called `front-page.php` with this on top to make it a `home` template:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Home
*/
?>
```

The function is removing the scripts, but it's removing them on all pages. I want the scripts to only load for the home page. I've tried `if ( !is_page_template('home.php') ) {` and also `if ( !is_front_page() ) {` but they both produced the same outcome as the first.

```
function wpcyclone_dequeue_script() {
   wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-cycle2' );
   wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-cycle2-swipe' );
   wp_dequeue_script( 'cyclone-client' );
}
if ( !is_page('Home') ) {
    add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpcyclone_dequeue_script', 100 );
}
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just a few notes on your code

- You should dequeue and deregister a script to remove it completely from the `$wp_scripts` global
- You should not be using `wp_print_scripts`, this is the wrong hook. You should be using `wp_enqueue_scripts`
- Don't wrap your action in a conditional. Your conditional tag might either be set to early or to late and might cause unexpected behavior.
- There is a dedicated conditional tag for the frontpage, `is_front_page()` that you can use to check if your page is the front page

Your code should look something like this

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', PHP_INT_MAX );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
    if ( !is_front_page() ) {
        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-cycle2' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-cycle2' );

        wp_dequeue_script( 'jquery-cycle2-swipe' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-cycle2-swipe' );

        wp_dequeue_script( 'cyclone-client' );
        wp_deregister_script( 'cyclone-client' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out through another way:

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'my_deregister_javascript', 100 );

function my_deregister_javascript() {
   if ( !is_page('Home') ) {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-cycle2' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery-cycle2-swipe' );
    wp_deregister_script( 'cyclone-client' );
     }
}
```

Still curious why the previous way didn't work.

Comment: In your 'settings' under 'reading' do you have the static home page set? Could explain why last example not working...

Comment: @Matt Yes, I do.